# Is doing Ph.D from a US university regarded as an absolute advantage in future career for international students?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, ranking, business-school

According to the UTD Top 100 Business School Research Ranking, there are some Asian (Hong Kongese) universities that rank higher than many US and Canadian universities. What are important factors to consider for international students in case of Ph.D admission especially with respect to funding, region and ranking of the university?
And with respect to future career, networking with academics, publication, shouldn't international students aiming for a Ph.D prefer the US first?

Comment: It depends on what your ultimate goal is. If you want to work in a US university of company then there are going to be some advantages (all else equal), but much less so if you want to work in Asia or Europe.

Comment: @ Roger Fan: I think US degree is more appealing in case of academics position in the universities of Asian countries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most important factors is in which country you plan to work after getting your diploma. E.g., if you plan to work in France, some French diplomas are just as valuable as "top" US schools.